# Find the largest Pair in an integer

Tags: c#, .net

I'm playing around with numbers, and I'm looking to write a small program that will return the largest double-digit of an integer that's passed in for example:

I pass in 2215487
it should return 87

I pass in 98765499
It should return 99

I've tried looking at Math.Max, but I don't believe that's what I'm looking for unless I have overlooked it

Comment: You might be thinking of `Enumerable.Max()` from LINQ, to which you could pass a `Func<string, int>` that handles each pair of digits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can divide by 10 each time and then compare the remainder of dividing the remaining number by 100. For example:

```cs
int v = 98765499;
int m = 0;
v = Math.Abs(v); // negate negative numbers so that we can process these too
while (v >= 10) // if you want to accept single digit initial values for V change this to v > 0
{
    m = Math.Max(m, v % 100);
    v /= 10;
}
Console.WriteLine(m);
```

We use `v >= 10` because we don't want to consider single-digit numbers (e.g. an initial value of v = 5).

`v % 100` uses the [remainder operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-) to give us the value left over when we divide by 100.

`v /= 10` divides `v` by 10 and stores the result in `v`.

I've used `Math.Abs( )` to make this work with negative numbers too, though you can take this line out if you only care about positive numbers.

At the end, `m` will either hold 0 (for single digit numbers or zero) or the highest two-digit value.

---

Example execution flow:

| Initial V | V % 100 | New V |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 98765499 | 99 | 9876549 |
| 9876549 | 49 | 987654 |
| 987654 | 54 | 98765 |
| 98765 | 65 | 9876 |
| 9876 | 76 | 987 |
| 987 | 87 | 98 |
| 98 | 98 | 9 |

Highest `v % 100` is 99.

---

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/ZZJP31875)

Comment: Working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution would be as follows:

```
    var thenumber = 987654990;
    var s = thenumber.ToString();
    var max = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < s.Length-1; i++) {
        int d1 = (int)(s[i] - '0');
        int d2 = (int)(s[i+1] - '0');
        max = Math.Max(max, 10*d1+ d2);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(max);
```

Ie, just iterate over the number and calculate the "pair" at the current position (consisting of the current digit `d1` and the next one `d2`) if the pair is greater than the current max, make it the new max ...